# Slow admin dialogue in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

When I run a program as Administrator I have to enter my password in an extra dialogue box. But it always takes a long time (about 40 seconds), before the password field is shown. It's says "looking for login information" (or something similar, my OS is not in English).

I have tried to make a screenshot, but it doesn't seem to work when this dialogue box is being shown.

My system:

- Acer 6920
- Windows 7 Enterprise with all updates
- Intel Core 2 Duo, 32 bit

Do you have any solution idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 UAC lightbox is slow to appear - can it be speeded up?](http://superuser.com/questions/94040/windows-7-uac-lightbox-is-slow-to-appear-can-it-be-speeded-up)

Comment: follow this and give me the ETL file: http://pastebin.com/iebjY3ne

Comment: have you captured a trace?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: follow the link that I posted

Comment: looks like you don't want help.